# Map from object to a dynamic string

Tags: java

Right now I have about 60 `Message` types which are passed to a `getStuff(Message)` method of a class which implements `ContainerOfThings`. There are multiple variations of an `ContainerOfThings` such as `BoxOfStuff` and `BagOfTricks` both of which realize the `getStuff(Message)` method which generates a string based on member variables. The result may also have pre-pended or post-pended data such as labels or concatenated data. See code below.

```
public class BoxOfStuff implements ContainerOfThings
{
    private String var1;
    private String var2;
    private String varN; 

    public String getStuff(Message message)
    {
        if (message.equals(Message.GET_STUFF1))
            return var1;
        else if (message.equals(Message.GET_STUFF2))
            return "Var2 is: " + var2;
        else if (message.equals(Message.GET_STUFFN))
            return varN + "\n";
        // Etc. for each Message.GET_*
    }
    // getters and setters for each var*
}

public class Message
{
    private String id = null;

    private Message(String id)
    {       this.id = id;   }

    public final String toString()
    {       return this.id; }

    public static final Message GET_STUFF1 = new Message("V1");
    public static final Message GET_STUFF2 = new Message("V2");
    public static final Message GET_STUFFN = new Message("VN");

}
```

I am trying to find a design that meets the following objectives. (1) The string returned from getStuf() needs to reflect the current state of the implementing class's member fields. (2) Also I would prefer to get away from an incredibly long series of `if / else if` blocks. One concern is ease of potentially changing to a persistent data-driven configurable object approach which a `Map` lends well towards. (3) Design should allow for simple maintenance and/or edits.

One design that could work but is a little messy is to create a Map with all key/values initialized in the constructor and also reset any key/value pair inside each setter method. In this way, the response to `getStuff(Message)` is updated to the new content after changes (ie: in a `setVar*()` method). Any other thoughts?

Comment: To clarify: you want to create a `Map<Message,String>` where `String` formats the output?

Comment: The String should contain the current value of any referenced member variable (current as of the time that getStuff() is called) and have any pre-pended or post-pended string data.

Comment: Does the formatting of the result string for a Message type vary accross the IContainerOfThings implementations?

Comment: Yes the format may vary depending on the implementing class.

Comment: Is Message an enum or a class? Show the definition of Message.

Comment: Declaration of Message added. It's a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need two maps. One will be a `Map<Message, String>` where the value will be a format string (i.e. something that will get passed into `String.format()`). The second map will be a `Map<Message, Field>` which should be fairly self explanatory once you take a look at the reflection libs. These will need to be setup at init time but after that the `getStuff()` method should be fairly clean and your setters won't be affected at all.

BTW, Java doesn't generally prefix interfaces with `I`.

Comment: I tried out an implementation similar to this one today. Reflection accomplishes the desired effect of having a Map that outputs dynamic strings. The only potential maintenance problem I see is mismatches created when field names are refactored. I'll do some reading and see if I can find a good way to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your problem, but it sounds like you want to [**memoize**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the result of your `getStuff()` call.

One easy way to do this is to use the [`makeComputingMap()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#makeComputingMap%28com.google.common.base.Function%29) method from the [`MapMaker`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) class in the Google [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library.

For example, you could do:

```
Map<Message, String> map = new MapMaker()
    .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .makeComputingMap(
       new Function<Message, String>() {
         public String apply(Message message) {
             // Your getStuff() implementation here
         }
       });
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Definitely interesting... I like it but it seems like series of if /else if statements would just move to the body of the Function declaration in order to populate the cache.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public abstract class BaseOfBox implements IContainerOfThings {
    protected final Map<Message, String> stuffs = 
            new HashMap<Message, String>();

    public final String getStuff(Message message) {
        return stuffs.get(message);
    }
}

public class BoxOfStuff extends BaseOfBox {
    private String var1;
    private String var2;

    public BoxOfStuff() {
        super();
    }

    public setVar1(String var1) {
        this.var1 = var1;
        stuffs.put(Message.GET_STUFF1, var1);
    }

    public setVar2(String var2) {
        this.var2 = var2;
        stuffs.put(Message.GET_STUFF2, "Var2 is: " + var2);
    }
    ...
}
```

Frankly, I think this is a pretty ugly solution, but so are the requirements, IMO.  I suspect a more elegant solution can only be found if we review the (real) requirements

Comment: I was hoping to find a design where (1) Computation of the getStuff response could be performed on-demand; and (2) Get away from the O(n) if / else if series. Yours certainly accomplishes #2.

Comment: Well, maybe you just need the `Message` instances to have an `enum` field so that `getStuff()` can use a `switch` statement.

Comment: @Citizen: Your comment clarifies your question considerably; would you mind editing your question to include this?  Also, `if` / `else if` blocks are not necessarily O(n) -- depending on your tests, the compiler may be able to do better than that.  But it's probably a moot point -- unless you have thousands of `else if` statements, the performance hit will most likely be inconsequential.

Comment: @Daniel: I updated the question. Your point about the run time is valid. I realized another reason I try to steer clear of conditional chains. With a map, it is later possible to change the BoxOfStuff to a data-driven configurable object.